# Conditional RUN in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile I have this line:

```
ARG ENV
RUN [ "$ENV" = "prod" ] && cp config.py.j2 config.py
```

However when I build the image it shows:

The command '/bin/sh -c [ "($ENV)" = "prod" ] && cp config.py.j2 config.py' returned a non-zero code: 1

How can I get this work?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the file you are trying to copy is not accessible? Did you try that command in it's parts? Maybe just trying `RUN cp config.py.j2 config.py` see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return code of a failed boolean expression in the shell  is `1`.  Try it:

```
$ [ "1" = "0" ] && echo equal
$ echo $?
1
```

That's exactly what you're seeing.  You can explicitly return 0 in every case by adding `|| :` to the end of the expression:

```
$ [ "1" = "0" ] && echo equal || :
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Ahh that's why. The command run as intended but returned a failed status. Adding the `||` part worked. Thank you.